# Can't install Grafana properly with influxdb 2.0 and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, influxdb

Grafana is installed correctly. The UI works just fine, but I can't connect it to influxdb bucket. Can you help me with that? Here is the docker_compose.yml file. Is there an issue with that file? I tried many things be but none worked fine

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.6.1
    container_name: influxdb
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_MODE=setup
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=admin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=wd9598%%DD
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=day_trading_organization
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=day_trading_bucket
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_TOKEN=21bc9ec3d7187f0087b4d5ae329afce4cfea8cdb27a0cd516a92efead753217d
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    networks:
      - influxdb_network
    volumes:
      - influxdb_storage:/var/lib/influxdb

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana_server
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=wd9598%%DD
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    networks:
      - influxdb_network
    volumes:
      - grafana_storage:/var/lib/grafana

volumes:
  influxdb_storage:
  grafana_storage:

networks:
  influxdb_network:
```

Comment: Clarify what does mean "can't connect it to influxdb". Do you get an error or you don't know how?

Comment: Hello, can you show the logs for the compose?, exposing only the `.yaml` it is complex to understand the error. Could you provide more information about your problem?

Comment: Also, can you hide your passwords, token, private keys?, a more advanced user could steal your credentials, be careful with that.